# При нажатии F5 символ переноса строки убирается

Tags: visual-studio, ide, settings

При нажатии на F5 `Visual Studio` сама убирает переносы строк. Какую настройку нужно убрать*?
ps. У меня также стоит Resharper. 
https://giphy.com/gifs/3o6ZsSJow77rnP4r0A

Comment: Это Resharper 100%, если его отключить все работает? https://resharper-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/206009269-Strange-braces-behavior?page=1#community_comment_205815295

Comment: спасибо)! это из за него